# Understanding how selenium works

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

So I have a script in python, using selenium and chrome driver. I'm wondering if when I make a call like

```
driver.executescript('return document.readyState')
# OR
driver.find_element_by_xpath('blah')
```

Does this make a request to the site? Can they tell I'm searching the html or executing any scripts? Or is this all on the document once it loads and is local.

I keep getting an error of "Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted" which to me means that I'm  using up all the sockets to fast.

Comment: i am not an expert and there is not enough information in the selenium documentation but you can test requests being made with Fiddler. Some functions will send a web request others will work with already downloaded DOM

Comment: I don't think it makes any requests because the site in question would have probably already banned me as they are notorious for that. I think I'm getting the error because I have chrome browser open while running the chrome web driver via selenium. They're both trying to bind to the same ip.

Comment: I have never hit this problem and was using both the browser as well as the driver at the same time. Have you checked your web response messages? Does that give you any clues? Where does your error message come from? [Are there multiple threads making requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14655041/6492655)

Comment: Where do you get this error? Are you trying to reuse the driver object across threads?

Answer (score 0):

So it seems like having a driver.execute_script('stuff') in a loop is what was causing the socket error. Still not sure why. I've added some wait's using the WebDriverWait to keep the script in check and now there's no problems.